# Xamarin.UWP bug

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

There should be a bug in DotNetNativeToolChain.  In project_name.UWP.csproj file, I have

```
<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
```

In xaml, I have

```
<Image x:Name="testimage"></Image>
```

In code behind file, I have

```
testimage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("project_name.testimage1.png");
```

testimage1.png is entered into project_name.csproj as

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="testimage1.png" />
```

Project can compile but crash with an error "Unhandled exception at 0x(Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in .exe. 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred."

If I comment out the "UseDotNetNativeToolchain" in project_name.UWP.csproj file, the application runs smoothly.

Comment: Did it work on iOS and Android device ? Your code works fine on my side . The error maybe caused by codes. About Embedded Images you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969480/how-to-load-the-online-pdf-files-in-xamarin-webview/58974415#58974415

Comment: Yes. It works on iOS and Android devices.  It works on UWP as well if I commented out the UseDotNetNativeToolchain.

Comment: Lucas, there is no link given.  Thanks.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57179/uwp-immediate-crash-in-release-mode

Comment: The issue is due to Reflection in DotNetNativeToolChain for UWP.  Eventually, I solved it writing a function shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ImageSource GetImageSource(string resource)
{
  ImageSource imagesource = null;
  Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
  {
    if (stream != null)
    {
      stream.CopyTo(ms);
      imagesource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()));
    }
  }
  return imagesource;
}
```

In the code, I use

```
testimage.Source = GetImageSource("project_name.testimage1.png");
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .